# How to refresh JTextField's value to match real value?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, numbers, jformattedtextfield

I'm doing this form that asks for Name,Lastname, Gender, Height, etc...
I've added keyTyped action handler to do integrity checks, (Name only letters, Age max 2 numbers, etc.)

The thing is, the checkers works, but the value I can see in the form doesn't match with the real value, for example I write '1.333' (in meters) for Height, the checker does its job and tells the user that only accepts values like 1.33.

So I used

```
formattedTextField.setText(StringUtils.substring(formattedTextField.getText(), 0, 4));
```

If I write 1.333 in the TextField, the real value stored is 1.33, BUT the 1.333 stays in the TextField

This is what I've tried

```
    formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    formattedTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            String re1="^([+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)$";
            System.out.println(formattedTextField.getText().matches(re1));
            if(formattedTextField.getText().length() >= 1 &&  formattedTextField.getText().matches(re1) == true)
            {                       

                if(formattedTextField.getText().length() >= 3)
                {
                    final BalloonTip balloonTip = new BalloonTip(
                            formattedTextField,
                            new JLabel("<html>Solo se aceptan valores de altura, como 1.66, 1.76, 1.88, etc..</html>"),
                            style,
                            BalloonTip.Orientation.LEFT_ABOVE,
                            BalloonTip.AttachLocation.ALIGNED,
                            20, 10,
                            false
                        );
                    TimingUtils.showTimedBalloon(balloonTip, 4500);
                    formattedTextField.setText(StringUtils.substring(formattedTextField.getText(), 0, 4));



                }
            }

        }
    });
contentPane.add(formattedTextField, "cell 2 9,growx,aligny center");
```

[image: Example]

Comment: As per comments to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864104/how-can-add-a-button-to-get-two-values), please create and post a valid [mcve]. This is not your entire program but rather a very short simple program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: And you never want to use a KeyListener on a Swing text component. Again, please improve your question if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
Create 3 global variables:

```
private String oldValue;
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+\\.?\\d{0,2}$");
private Matcher matcher;
```

And you need store old value and comprare new value with regex

```
formattedTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            oldValue = formattedTextField.getText();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(formattedTextField.getText());
        if(!matcher.matches()){
            formattedTextField.setText(oldValue);
        }
    }
}
```